# CSS: Float left and position absolute

Tags: css

I have this bar chart created with CSS
[image]

```
.barGraph {
    background: url(images/horizontal_grid_line_50_pixel.png) bottom left;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #333;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    }

.barGraph li {
    background: #666 url(images/bar_50_percent_highlight.png) repeat-y top right;
    border: 1px solid #555;
    border-bottom: none;
    bottom: 0; 
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 0; 
    float: left; 
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 39px;
    }
```

When I add

```
.barGraph li {
    position: absolute;
    }
```

The bars don't float anymore and turn out like this: [image]
is there a way to get it like this? [image]

HTML:

```
<ul class="barGraph">               
    <li class="set1" style="height: 57px;">57</li>
    <li class="set1" style="height: 154px;">154</li> 
    <li class="set1" style="height: 99px;">99</li>
    <li class="set1" style="height: 57px;">57</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: position:absolute will use top, bottom, left, right to position, it will not float. You need some JS to set it top: -xxx; where xxx is height of bars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Float:left and position:absolute together don't make sense. Instead, set the list items to `display:inline-block;` and `vertical-align:bottom;`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xyv9pb3e/1)**